# Why does fetch return 302 status code but XHR doesn't?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, ecmascript-6, fetch, es6-promise

I'm using [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to query my own WordPress REST API endpoint. However, every request that I make with fetch ends up with a infinite loop of 302 status codes until fetch finally errors with TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

[image: illustration of problem]

This is on Chrome 56, using the native fetch. But when I visit the endpoint using my browser, use XHR or Postman, I always get 200 as the status.

XHR on the other hand...

[image: XHR doesn't suffer from this problem]

Code relevant to this problem:

```
  static checkStatus(email = null) {
    const cookie = Cookies.get('cookiename');
    const data = email || cookie;

    if (!cookie && !email) {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('No data given.'));
    }

    // This works.
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      request({
        url: `/wp-json/woo/donate/status/?email=${data}`,
        method: 'GET',
        success: (response) => {
          resolve(response);
        },
        error: (error) => {
          reject(error);
        }
      })
    });

    // This doesn't.
    return fetch(`/wp-json/woo/donate/status/?email=${data}`, {
      method: 'GET',
    });
  }
```

Please note that I do not actually have two consecutive return statements in my code, that's just for demo. I'm using `request()` as a wrapper to XHR, you can find the [source for that here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/k1sul1/1e34a2c5eab0f7d903037c0e3e8605e1/raw/5762ab8dd0e83ebf6a0b505acb18b0151dc8ab5f/request.js).

So how do I go around this? I know fetch is still "experimental", but I've used it in several already shipped projects by bundling a polyfill to browsers that don't support it just yet. This is a new thing.

Comment: Before someone asks, it's the same result if I use `/wp-json/` instead of `/wp-json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem was resolved by "rebuilding" WordPress by destroying my local Vagrant machine, and starting it again.

For once, turning it on and off again fixed the problem.

Comment: I'm getting the exact same problem. I guess I'll try the same